# VBA Insert Method of Range Object Fails/Object Invoked

Tags: vba, excel

I have read many solutions but none have worked... My code has been working fine for 2 weeks but now it is failing at the following line:
    `Sheets("Order Forms").Range(Cells(25 + intAbove, intCol - 3), Cells(25 + intAbove, intCol + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

I have tried re-writing it by using `Select` and then `Selection` but nothing worked. It still works sometimes if I run some other macros first. I get both errors mentioned in the subject.

Here's my entire procedure if that helps...

```
Sub Modify_List(ByVal intNewVal As Integer, ByVal intOldVal As Integer, strType As String, intCol As Integer)
Dim intA1 As Integer
Dim intA2 As Integer
Dim intAbove As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case strType
    Case "Standard User Phones - Cisco 7965"
        intAbove = 0
        intCol = intCol + 1

    Case "Public Space Phones - Cisco 7965"
        intAbove = Cells(17, intCol - 1).Value
        If intAbove > 0 Then
            intAbove = intAbove + 2
        End If

    Case "Public Space Phones - Cisco 8831"
        intA1 = Cells(17, intCol - 1).Value
        intA2 = Cells(17, intCol).Value

        If intA1 + intA2 = 0 Then
            intAbove = 0
        ElseIf intA1 = 0 Then
            intAbove = intA2 + 2
        ElseIf intA2 = 0 Then
            intAbove = intA1 + 2
        Else
            intAbove = intA1 + intA2 + 4
        End If

End Select

Select Case intNewVal
    Case Is = intOldVal
        'do nothing

    Case Is < intOldVal
        'remove rows

        If intNewVal = 0 Then
            'remove header and lines
            Range(Cells(25 + intAbove, intCol - 3), Cells(26 + intAbove + intOldVal, intCol + 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Cells(20, intCol).Select
        Else
            'remove ending lines
            Range(Cells(26 + intAbove + intNewVal + 1, intCol - 3), Cells(26 + intAbove + intOldVal, intCol + 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Cells(26 + intAbove + intNewVal, intCol - 2).Select

        End If

    Case Is > intOldVal
        'add rows

        If intOldVal = 0 Then
            'add header and lines
            SheetAU.Range("B1").Value = strType
            SheetAU.Range("A1:E2").Copy
            'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Order Forms").Activate
            **Sheets("Order Forms").Range(Cells(25 + intAbove, intCol - 3), Cells(25 + intAbove, intCol + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown**
            Application.CutCopyMode = False


            For i = 1 To intNewVal
                SheetAU.Range("A3:E3").Copy
                Sheets("Order Forms").Range(Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol - 3), Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol - 3).Value = i
            Next

            Cells(27 + intAbove, intCol - 2).Select

        Else
            'insert extra lines
            For i = intOldVal + 1 To intNewVal
                SheetAU.Range("A3:E3").Copy
                Sheets("Order Forms").Range(Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol - 3), Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Cells(26 + intAbove + i, intCol - 3).Value = i
            Next

            Cells(26 + intAbove + intOldVal + 1, intCol - 2).Select

        End If

End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Automation error: the object invoked has dosconnected from its clients.

Comment: Excel actually freezes after this error and I am forced to close from the task manager.

Comment: Have you checked that `strType` matches the values you've checked for in your first `Select` statement? If it doesn't match any of them (due to a small typo perhaps) then it's possible that the `Select` statement is skipped over without ever assigning a value to intAbove, leaving it at its default value of 0.

Comment: Qualify those `Cells` with a worksheet object, otherwise they refer to the ActiveSheet.  You should never rely on any particular sheet being active when your code runs.

Comment: @aiken they are being assigned correctly prior to the select. When I debug, intabove has a value of 0 (which is fine) and intcol is 4.

Comment: @TimWilliams I just added `SheetB1` (which is the codename of sheets("Order Forms")) before all `Cells` and i get the following error: Method 'Insert' of Object 'Range' failed. I have been getting one of these two errors whenever I change somethign to try to fix this.

Comment: Try to insert the cells manually. Maybe you have some stray data in the bottom row (or formatting) and it won't let you shift those cells off the bottom. If you can't do it manually, you may get a better error message. Also, make sure the sheet isn't protected.

Comment: @DickKusleika inserting manually works fine... If i break it out into a with statement, it fails and the debugger highlights `.Insert (xlDown)`

Comment: I am beginning to think that this workbook has some type of big bug. I had an issue (and it's happening again now) where a procedure crashes due to a command in the procedure that isn't even called (there is an if statement and the command is in the else when it isn't even reaching the else) yet the fact that it is in the editor is making it crash.

Comment: Did you ever press Ctrl+Break? I've had situations where that has caused that kind of strange behavior. Download CodeCleaner for vba and clean your code. Can't hurt.

Comment: after testing this on a co-workers computer (and it worked fine..) I deleted all of my temp files and now it only crashes when the intNewVal is 5.... so I have to figure out why...

Comment: finally, have you solved this problem? I hit into the same error today.